# Multiple class inheritence

Tags: python-2.7

Would like to have class C contain all the defined options and common functions, then have classes A and B inherit them. Class C should also return a chosen classes main method via the option call.

1. Is the use of super here correct?
2. Are there better alternative ways to do the same?

My attempt:

```
class A(object):
    def main(self):
        print "A"
        print self.test
        return True

class B(object):
    def main(self):
        print "B"
        print self.test
        return False

class C(A,B):
    def __init__(self, options):
        self.__call = options.get('call')
        self.test = "test"

    def main(self):
        if self.__call == 'A':
            return super(C, self).main()
        if self.__call == 'B':
            return super(A, self).main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print C({"call": "B"}).main()
    print([cls.__name__ for cls in C.mro()])
```

Example of A,B inheriting from C - @Khalid

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self, options):
        self.__call = options.get('call')
        self.test = "test"

class A(C):
    def __init__(self, opt):
        super(A, self).__init__(opt)

    def main(self):
        print "A"
        print self.test
        return True

class B(C):
    def __init__(self, opt):
        super(B, self).__init__(opt)

    def main(self):
        print "B"
        print self.test
        return False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    opts = {"call": "B"}
    if opts.get('call') == 'A':
        print A(opts).main()
    if opts.get('call') == 'B':
        print B(opts).main()
    print([cls.__name__ for cls in C.mro()])
```

Comment: You've done it in reverse, class A and B should be inheriting from C - in your example C is inheriting from A and B.

Comment: Yeah, I originally did this, but didn't seem so clean. I basically wanted C to encapsulate the options and calling the chosen class therein.

Comment: What do you mean "seem so clean"? Its doing what you want _"Would like to have class C contain all the defined options and common functions, then have classes A and B inherit them."_ in this scenario A and B must inherit from C. The only thing I could recommend is `opts = {'call': A}` and then `opts['call'](opts).main()`

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Meaning > I basically wanted C to encapsulate the options and calling the chosen class therein.